# How can I introduce input lag (keyboard and mouse) to my system?

Tags: windows, input, lag

(I work in QA, this really is for legitimate use.)

I'm trying to come up with a way to introduce forced input lag for both keyboard and mouse (in Windows).  Like, when I press 'A' on the keyboard, I want to introduce a very slight delay before the OS processes that A.  Or if I move the mouse, I'd like the same mouse speed, but just with the same slight delay before it kicks in.  This lag needs to be present across any threads, not just the one that kicked off the process.  But, the lag doesn't have to be to-the-millisecond precise every time.

I'm not even sure how to go about setting this up.  I'm capable of writing it in whatever language/environment we may need, I'm just not sure where to start.  I think something like AutoHotkey may be able to do what I want by essentially making an arbitrary key call a macro that delays very slightly before sending that key, but I'm not sure what function calls I may need to make it happen.  Or, maybe there's a way in C to get at the input across the OS before it kicks in.  I'm just not sure.

Can anyone can point me to some resources or a language/function(s) that can accomplish this?  (Or even an already existing program or service.)

Comment: Perhaps better suited on [Software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) or [SQA.SE](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want purely software solution, I’m afraid you’ll need to develop a filter driver for your keyboard and mouse. Very expensive to develop.

Instead, you can plug your mouse and keyboard into somewhere else, have the input messages come through the network, and then introduce network latency. You could use second PC + VNC software, or second PC + [software USB/IP](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/), or hardware USB/IP device [like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DQDSK0U).

There’s an easy but less reliable way.

You could develop a system-wide WH_KEYBOARD_LL and WH_MOUSE_LL hooks, discard original messages, and after a while send the delayed messages with SendInput API. This should work mostly, however there’re cases where it wont, e.g. I don’t expect anything happens with most videogames because raw input.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  Our scenario is essentially trying to simulate network latency locally to demonstrate whether its detrimental to the experience or not without the need to force latency.  But, it was a small investigation task, so I may just go back with that: If they want network latency, they should just get a latent network. :)

Comment: Speaking about network latency, presentation latency is usually much higher than input latency. Keyboard/mouse traffic is tiny; the latency is essentially a ping/2. However, presentation traffic (vnc/remote desktop/vmware PCoIP/whatever else you’re using for your remoting) is huge compared to input, and also compression/decompression happens, so usually the presentation latency will be much higher than input latency.